# Secure android application made by ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework

I'm working on an android apps. I am using ionic framework. In some pages I need to get data from a web server and the result is an object `json`.

My problem is if some one arrives to `GET` the pages where I get the `json` data, one can fetch all my database data by changing the http request.

Is there any way that can improve security of my apps?

Answer (score 0):

You should make some kind of authentication mechanism, for example, a token in the header, that way you know wether the user has access to that resource or not.

So when you make your request you can generate a configuration for that particular request.

**Example:**

```
var url = "http://yourserver.com/api/your/path";
var config = {
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer someBearerFromTheServer"
    }
};
$http.get(url, config);
```

The backend implementation for this to work depends on the language you use. Here google is your best friend.

A more advanced way to do this, is to use interceptors in the $http service and attach the token to the header in every request, but be careful, you should secure this so you won't send your credentials to every request you make (sometimes your app might need to request data from another server).

You can read more about $http services and its configurations in the [$http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Regards